# How to implement optional attributes in a class

Tags: c++, class, attributes, option-type

I have a class `MyClass` mainly based on one member `Attribute`. What is the best possibility to implement optional members `Optional1` and `Optional2` into the class definition. The idea is that in some cases there is more information about the `MyClass`-object which should be added to it.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    double Attribute;
    //double Optional1; //that's what I want to implement
    //double Optional2; //that's what I want to implement
public:
    MyClass(Attribute);
    void setAttribute(double);
    //void setOptional1(double);
    //...
};
```

I think there is nothing like a really optional member in a class, so I probably have to deal with default values in the constructor. Something like

```
MyClass(Attribute, Optional1 = -1, Optional2 = -1)
```

If `-1` is never set in a normal case, I know for sure that `Optional1` and/or `Optional2` "is not set". If it is different from -1, I know it has an intented value.

However, this approach seems to be a bit ugly and I wonder if there is some better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be searching for `std::optional<>` if it's runtime-optional or bool template parameter(s) if it's compile-time optional. But, first and foremost, verify your design: are we talking about the same class and not a class hierarchy?

Comment: I generalized the question to keep it clear. The class is actually called ``Line`` with the Attribute being the ``Endpoints`` of a line. In some cases I know more about the line, e.g. the ``Color`` (rgb-values). So in these cases I want to add the color corresponding to that line. I think that is much easier than to have a ``vector<Line>`` and a corresponding ``vector<Color>``. As I'm not so familiar with C++ yet, it's difficult for me to assess the correct way to implement this. I will have a look at your suggestion about ``std::optional<>`` or can you provide further infos regarding it?

Comment: @Phann: in this case, you probably have a class hierarchy. There's a Line and a ColoredLine that inherits from Line - or, even better, Line, Colored and `class ColoredLine : public Line, public Colored`. Then, of course, your vector will store pointers and you'll have virtual functions. Do this if you can define meaningful actions on the base (i.e., `draw()`); if any combination of available|n/a parameters are valid, do it with optional.